# Check whether a particular child exists or not in some root

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-xml

I am parsing an xml through DOM parser and I have to check that whether a partcular child exists or not in the xml. For example

```
 <Employee>
      <Emp>
         <Name>          A     </Name>
         <Designation>   C     </Designation>
         <Experience>    D     </Experience>
     </Emp>
      <Emp>
         <Name>          x     </Name>
         <Designation>   y     </Designation>   
     </Emp>

</Employee>
```

and so on...As you can see "experience" tag is present for some employees and may not be present for other. How I can check whether Experience tag is present for any employee or not. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: plese refer first ::
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646352/need-help-regarding-data-manipulation-data-uploading-and-data-download-invloving

Comment: @Scorpio absolutely irrelevant to my question...Please suggest something relevant. Thank you.

Comment: @scorpio - link is broken when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Well this thing can be checked.You can write a piece of code to check this tag is present or not.In case of tag not present you can return some value may be `null`.

```
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"emp"])
        {
            attributeOfColoumn = [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Experience"];
            if([attributeOfColoumn isEqualToString:@""])
            {
            return yes;
            }
    }
```